# postgresql: получение доступа к столбцам с одинаковыми названиями разных таблиц, объединённых через Join

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

Есть 2 таблицы `tbl1` и `tbl2` в которых есть одинаковое поле `words`, содержащую разную информацию

```
WITH selected_t AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
        tbl1 
    LEFT JOIN
        tbl2
    USING(id)
)
SELECT 
    extract(year from t1.date) as year, string_to_table(t2.words, ';') AS word
FROM 
    selected_t;
```

Можно ли как-то достучаться до поля `words` из таблицы `tbl2`?
Или только через переименования полей решать данную задачу?

Как вариант конечно можно было бы делать вместо `SELECT *`:

```
SELECT t1.date AS date, t2.words AS words
```

Но интересует возможность именно работать со всеми полями (*), потому что к приведённому коду еще произвольный `WHERE` может подключаться

Comment: `WITH selected (column1, column2, ...) AS (...) SELECT ...`.

Comment: Вам в любом случае придется дать имена всем колонкам в CTE. Так  и дайте разные имена.